# PostgreSQL count of double items

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table

```
region_id | zip_code
    1     |   10001   
    1     |   10002
    2     |   89001
```

I have data with zip codes - 10001, 89001, 10001, 10002

I need to calculate count zip codes for each region (include duplicate zipcodes).

```
region_id | count
    1     |   3   
    2     |   1
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT region_id, COUNT(region_id) as count FROM my_table 
WHERE zip_code in ('10001','89001','10001','10002') GROUP BY region_id;
```

But this query return 2 count for 1 region_id, that is not ok for me.

I already did it just with for loop in my language, but maybe it can be done with SQL for better performance.

Comment: `count` does not count how many values occur in your `IN` clause, it counts records. There are 2 records in your table matching region 1. If you want to count the values that are in your `IN` clause, do that wherever you derive those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to account duplicates in your input (not in your actual table), you just need a `join`:

```
select region_id, count(region_id) as "count"
from my_table
join unnest(array[10001, 89001, 10001, 10002]) zip_code using (zip_code)
group by region_id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/52f2f/3)

---

*But I really can't think of any reason for which you need this; please update your question (provide us some more context) to help you find a possibly better solution.*

Comment: Thank you! It did exactly what I need. My whole logic is a little complex and it is just part of it.